# 2-d Array and pointer.

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
{
int a[10][10]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
int n;
n=FindSumLeavingOutRowCol(a, 3,3,1,2);
printf("%d",n);

}
int FindSumLeavingOutRowCol(int** arr, int m, int n, int k,int l)
{
int sum,i,j;
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        if((i==k)&&(j==l))
        {
            ;
        }
        else{
            sum+=*(*(a+i)+j);
        }
    }
    }
```

I am getting an error on passing the 2 d array also its telling 'a' undeclared. Please help me in sorting out the bug!

Comment: first step: format this code so it is readable. Also, we need a [mcve], so copy&paste, compile and run just works to reproduce your problem.

Comment: `a` is undeclared isn't a bug. You'll have bugs later when your code compiles... here it seems that `a` is declared in a different (not global) scope than the function, hence invisible.

Comment: btw, `a` has the type `int [10][10]`, so after adjusting to a pointer this is `int (*)[10]` and **not** `int **` as your function expects.

Comment: The variable `a` in `sum+=*(*(a+i)+j);` is not being declared, nor initialized at that moment. The compiler tries to find it but it is unable to do so. Perhaps you made a typo or wanted to use another variable.

Comment: A 2D array is **not** an array of pointers! You can look at this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47094008/3545273) from mine for more details (was C++ but it is exactly the same thing for raw arrays)

Comment: See [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) for an explanation what's the difference between 2D arrays and pointer-to-pointers (and why you shouldn't use the latter in most cases).

Comment: If you are getting an error, you need to post the full text of that error. Also, what is that first block meant to be? Was it a function? Please post full, readable code - not incomplete, terribly formatted fragments.

Comment: Will help, but where's your effort?

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in expressions as for example when used as arguments are converted to pointers to their first elements.

If you have an array like this

```
int a[10][10];
```

that can be rewritten like

```
int ( a[10] )[10];
```

that is it is an array of 10 elements of the type `int[10[` then in expressions it is converted to the type `int ( * )[10]`,

So for example you can write

```
int ( a[10] )[10] = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9} };
int (  *p   )[10] = a;
```

Thus the function should be declared like

```
int FindSumLeavingOutRowCol( int arr[][10], int m, int n, int k,int l);
```

that is the same as

```
int FindSumLeavingOutRowCol( int ( *arr )[10], int m, int n, int k,int l);
```

If the compiler supports variable length arrays and the variables `m` and `n` represent the dimensions (not the ranges) then the function can be also declared like

```
int FindSumLeavingOutRowCol( int m, int n, int arr[m][n], int k,int l);
```

or

```
int FindSumLeavingOutRowCol( int m, int n, int arr[][n], int k,int l);
```

or like

```
int FindSumLeavingOutRowCol( int m, int n, int ( *arr )[n], int k,int l);
```

Otherwise you will need to add two more parameters that specify the ranges apart from the dimensions.

Pay attention to that the variable `sum` is not initialized

```
int sum,i,j;
```

So the function will have undefined behavior.

And moreover the parameter is declared as having name `arr` not `a`.

And I hope the function has a return statement something like

```
return sum;
```

Comment: `int FindSumLeavingOutRowCol( int m, int n, int arr[m][n], int k,int l);` : Since `m` and `n` represent ranges in the array, not dimensions, you need to use different arguments  instead of `n` for dimension(`[n]`).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks. I have updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the simple one:

> also its telling 'a' undeclared.

```
int FindSumLeavingOutRowCol(int** arr, int m, int n, int k,int l)
{
    // [...]
            sum+=*(*(a+i)+j);
    // [...]
}
```

In this line, you reference `a` which exists neither in file scope nor in this function. You probably mean `arr` instead.

---

But the real problem is your first question:

> I am getting an error on passing the 2 d array

This is because your function expects a pointer to a pointer, which is **not** a pointer to (the first element of) a 2d-array.

From [n1570 (latest draft for C11)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

**§6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes), p7:**

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of *type*’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to
>   *type*’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the `[` and `]` of the
>   array type derivation. [...]

So, as arrays can't be passed to a function, pointers get passed instead and if you declare a function parameter as array type, it is automatically *adjusted* to a pointer type.

This is simple for 1d arrays. Say you have

```
int x[5];
```

and a function

```
void foo(int a[]);
```

then this function declaration is equivalent to

```
void foo(int *a);
```

and you can just pass your array like

```
foo(x);
```

because the identifier of an array also evaluates to a pointer to the first array element --> type `int *`.

With a 2d array, the same rules apply. You could write your function with an argument like this:

```
int foo(int arr[][10]);
```

Adjusting this to a pointer type would result in

```
int foo(int (*arr)[10]);
```

This is a **pointer to a 10-element array of `int`**. It is **not** a **pointer to a pointer**. The 10 elements of your `int a[10][10]` are each an array of 10 integers.